# Nesting resources error

Tags: ember.js

I've followed this example http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/ to implement a nested resource for my app but continue to receive route and type errors.

I've created my route as follows:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('logs', {path: '/'}, function(){
    this.resource('log', {path:'/logs/:log_id'}, function(){
      this.resource('triggers');
    });
  });
});
```

My controller:

```
App.TriggersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs:"log"
});
```

Model:

```
App.Log = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    type: DS.attr('string'),
    messages: DS.attr('string'),
    triggers: DS.hasMany(App.Trigger, {async:true})
});
```

Child Model:

```
App.Trigger = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    pattern: DS.attr('string'),
    isEnabled: DS.attr('boolean'),
    colour: DS.attr('string'),
    highlightText: DS.attr('boolean'),
    invertContrast: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

JSFiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/WZp9T/11/

Click on one of the links and you should see the error in console.

("Error while loading route: TypeError {}" and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'typeKey' of undefined" as well as a deprecation warning)

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is:

Logs -> Log -> Log Triggers -> Trigger

Each context should remain on screen, where exactly am I going wrong?

EDIT: It seems to be a problem with this:

```
App.LogIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    return this.store.find(params.log_id);
  }
});
```

If I remove that piece of code I no longer receive my errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the store which kind of object you want to look up. Right now you're just passing it an ID. This is probably what you're looking for:

```
App.LogIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    return this.store.find('log', params.log_id);
  }
});
```